# boolean values show as ints

Tags: python, shell, boolean, conditional-statements

[image]

What determines if '1' is the result or if 'True' is the result. ik that they both mean the same thing, but why is there different outputs in the shell?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`not` produces a boolean no matter what, but `and` and `or` always evaluate to one of their arguments.

`x and y` is equivalent to `y if x else x`.

`x or y` is equivalent to `x if x else y`.

Whether you get an int or a bool out of your test expressions depends on whether the `and`s and `or`s select one of your original integer values, or a boolean produced by `not`. For example, your `a or not b or (not a and b) and (b or a)` test finds that `a` is `1`, which is truthy, so the first `or` immediately returns `1` without evaluating anything on the right-hand side.